# Trying to write a SOQL query that will pull the "product" name from the PricebookEntry on an opportunity line item

Tags: soql, opportunity-lineitem

SO to clarify, The "name" on the OpportunityLineItem doesn't contain just the actual SKU, which is the "name" of the product. What I need to do is peel the onion back one more layer, and pull the Product SKU from the pricebookentry or something else I haven't thought of. Not sure if this is done through pricebookentry, or what. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is a Lookup to the product on Opportunity Line Item.

> SELECT Id,Product2Id,product2.name FROM OpportunityLineItem where
>   id='***'